I keep getting an Illegal instruction (core dumped) error when using a lyrics_extractor library in python
I have been looking everywhere for an answer and can't find anything
Full code:
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from lyrics_extractor import SongLyrics

window = Tk()#creating window
window.geometry('600x600')#giving size
window.title('Song lyrics')#giving title
head=Label(window, text="Enter the song you want Lyrics for", font=('Calibri 15'))# a lable
head.pack(pady=20)
result =tk.StringVar()#ensuring result is string type
song=tk.StringVar()#ensuring song is string type

def get_lyrics():
    song_name=song.get()# using get method getting value of song
    api_key = "AIzaSyAcZ6KgA7pCIa_uf8-bYdWR85vx6-dWqDg"
    engine_id = "aa2313d6c88d1bf22"
    extract_lyrics = SongLyrics(api_key, engine_id)# going to the website for which we have got the engine id
    song_lyrics = extract_lyrics.get_lyrics(song_name)#getting the lyrics
    result.set(song_lyrics)#setting the result

Entry(window, textvariable=song).pack()# enter a song name
Message(window,textvariable=result, bg="light grey").pack(side=TOP,anchor=W,fill=BOTH, expand=1)#displaying the lyrics
#create a button
Button(window, text="GO",command=get_lyrics).pack()

window.mainloop()

Note:
I did get it to work before once but now it keeps showing this error when I try to run it.
Expectation:
Window to open and ask for the title of a song.

it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
wildcard imports pollute the namespace.

What kind of processor do you have in your machine, what OS (including version) are you running on, and how did you acquire the libraries you're using (e.g., did you compile them, did you install pre-built wheels, did you get them from your distro, etc.)?

Running: Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon Version: 4.6.7

Processor: Pentium Dual-Core CPU E5500 @ 2.80GHz * 2
